# WordPress: кириллица при попадании в массив PHP становится нечитабельной

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress 4.9.7.

В нём есть пара статей на русском языке, некоторые данные из которых забираются в массив вот таким скриптом:

```
$args = array('numberposts'   => - 1, 'category_name' => sealed);
$args = array_map("utf8_encode", $args );
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
setup_postdata( $post );
$content = $post->post_content;
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
if (strpos($content, '<li>') !== false) {
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
    }
for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i ++) {
$names[] = $items->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
}

$names = array_unique($names);

echo $names;
```

WP отображает статьи правильно, то есть, читабельно, но при выводе массива, набранного из этих же статей, получаю вот такое **Ð¿ÑÐ¾Ð±Ð°** вместо **ПРОБА**.

С латиницей никаких проблем.

В настройках базы данных везде utf8_general_ci, тип базы MyISAM, хотя, InnoDB ведёт себя так же.

Уже весь мозг сломал. Есть вообще возможность полноценно работать с кириллицей в массивах PHP?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, надо показать код прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Ну а так-то, думаю, что вы не используете мультибайтовые функции работы со строками http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mbstring.php

Comment: Забыл добавить, хотя собирался. Исправил.

Comment: Не использую, похоже. Если есть возможность поправить мой код или ткнуть носом прямо в нужную статью с Вашей ссылки, буду признателен. Из меня кодер тот еще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главное - надо указать в `loadHTML`, что ваш контент в UTF-8.

Плюс `strpos` я заменил на `mb_strpos`.

И в `$args` у вас какая-то ошибка. Наверное, имя категории должно быть строкой: `'sealed'`.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => - 1,
    'category_name' => 'sealed',
);

$args  = array_map( 'utf8_encode', $args );
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $dom     = new \DOMDocument();
    if ( mb_strpos( $content, '<li>' ) !== false ) {
        $dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );
        $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
    }
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i ++ ) {
        $names[] = $items->item( $i )->nodeValue;
    }
}

$names = array_unique( $names );

echo $names;
```

Comment: Тут не поспоришь - о своих способностях в написании кода я сказал в ответе выше ;). Но всё прекрасно работало и без кавычек, наверное, поэтому я и не заметил ошибку. Большое спасибо, теперь всё показывает, как надо!

Comment: Php отсутствие кавычек иногда понимает правильно, и ставит их сам, выдавая при этом ошибку в лог.